# Ionic 4 IonSelect selected value text truncates way too soon

Tags: ionic-framework

I have a standard Ionic IonSelect set up as in the following...

```
<ion-item lines='none'>
      <ion-label>Location</ion-label>
      <ion-select type="text" placeholder='select...'>
        <ion-select-option *ngFor='let p of places' value="{{p.id}}">
          {{p.description}}
        </ion-select-option>
      </ion-select>
  </ion-item>
```

My problem is that it can only handle quite short text until it starts to truncate, eg:

[image]

It looks like the label and selected values want to use 50% of the space each.

Is there a way to make this text move to the left, almost all the way up to the label?

Ionic info:

```
    $ ionic info

    Ionic:

       Ionic CLI                     : 5.2.3 (C:\Users\pchapman\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
       Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.11.2
       @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.802.0
       @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.2.0
       @angular/cli                  : 8.2.0
       @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.0.0

    Cordova:

       Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
       Cordova Platforms : android 8.0.0, windows 6.0.1
       Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 3.1.2, (and 12 other plugins)

    Utility:

       cordova-res : 0.7.0-testing.0
       native-run  : 0.2.8

    System:

       Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\Users\pchapman\AppData\Local\Android\sdk)
       NodeJS            : v10.15.3 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
       npm               : 6.4.1
       OS                : Windows 10
```

### Update

Tried using the float as suggested, but I get:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just found your question while looking for the same. After some time trying to find useful hints unsuccessfully, I thought on providing my findings for future coders that will end up here as you might have solved your issue already.

TL;DR

the quickest fix for the ion-select alignment is to set up position on the label like this

```
 <ion-label position="floating">Location</ion-label>
```

so it ends up as

```
<ion-item  lines='none'>
  <ion-label position="floating">Location</ion-label>
  <ion-select type="text" placeholder='select...'>
    <ion-select-option *ngFor='let p of places' value="{{p.id}}">
      {{p.description}}
    </ion-select-option>
  </ion-select>
```

it will work with position floating or stacked, as it will wrap a new line for the select result.

This way you get still the same ionic components without many modifications and still solve the UI disarray.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but when I tried this, my select text gets pushed to a a new line (see image under UPDATE1). I do position my `ion-item` inside `css grid`, so maybe this does interfere in this particular case (though would not have thought so since the `ion-item` itself is not of `display:grid`. Was your example for Ionic 4+?

Comment: I'm sorry that my solution was not enough for your specific needs. As I explained there, it will wrap the select options in a new line. It was enough for me since the UI was much better.